# getting the value of request.GET in python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I tried to get the data in request.GET data however this gives me an empty values or None when printing.

```
class SchoolMixin(ProfileTypeRequiredMixin, MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin):
    profile_type = 'manager'

    permissions = {
        'any': ('school.admin')
    }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.init_vars(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return super(SchoolMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def init_vars(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.schools = self.request.user.manager.school

        self.vals(request)


    def vals(self, request):
        if not request.GET:
            if self.schools.school_set.exists():
                school = self.schools.school_set.all()[0].pk
            else:
                school = None
            data = {
                'school': school,
            }
        else:
            data = request.GET

        self.filter_form = forms.FilterForm(
            data=data,
            prefix='FILTER',
            school_manager=request.user.manager,
            user=request.user
        )
        self.filter_form.is_valid()
        self.school = self.filter_form.cleaned_data['school']


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(SchoolMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        data['filter_form'] = self.filter_form


        return data



class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    school = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=_('School'),
        required=False,
        queryset=School.objects.none(),
        empty_label=_('School'),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )
   ....
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.school_manager = kwargs.pop('manager')
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

url(r'^school/$', views.ExportView.as_view(), name='export'),

I tried on older branch and I get the value of request.GET, I use the self.request.GET but still I get an empty or None. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't find a reference to your method `init_vars(...)`, does that invoking from somewhere?

Comment: I already updated my code

Comment: By the looks of it, you missed at least one quote. The syntax highlighting on SA already shows. Please update your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

There's nothing wrong with the view code, I just add in html jquery require() and all data in request.POST is now printing.